# React Hooks: Render component after the value stored in context API has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am developing a web app in React. I am trying to do the following:

1. Get user information from the database and store it using the Context API.
2. Render the component when the context changes.

The problem is that there is apparently a time lag in updating the context and so the component does not re-render. How do I make sure that the component re-renders after the context value is updated?

Below is the code I am using:

```
 const User = () => {    
     const {userinfo, setuserinfo} = useContext(Userinfo) //Declare useContext hooks
     useEffect(()=>{
         /*
          Compute the value of mid
         */         
         setuserinfo(mid);  //Set 'userinfo' using context API
     },[])

     return (
         <>
         {userinfo.map(ui =>
          //JSX to map userinfo to UI components
         )}
         </>
     )
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the code where you define your context, especially the code for `setuserinfo`?

Answer (score 0):

You could check or verify `userinfo` before attempting to map it to rendered components.

E.g.

```js
// or use lodash.isNil, or lodash.isEmpty, or whatever check you want
const isNil = o => o === null || o === undefined; 

return ( isNil(userInfo) ?
  <span>Loading...</span> :
  <>
    {userinfo.map(ui =>
      //JSX to map userinfo to UI components
    )}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
return  userinfo && Array.isArray(userinfo) && userinfo.length ? (
         <>
         {userinfo.map(ui =>
          //JSX to map userinfo to UI components
         )}
         </>
       ) : <span>Loading... (or whatever)</span>;
```